# Can't even get a Hello World working with SwiftUI/Xcode 12

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

Starting from the simple iOS App template, I make my "ContentView.swift":

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      print("hello console!")
    }, label: {
      Text("Button")
    })
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

I start up a preview in `Debug Preview`, I activate the console so it shows up below, I see my button that says "Button". I click the button on the text that says "Button", but still see nothing.  What am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `Debug Preview`.

From [SwiftUI tips and tricks](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks):

> If you press play in the SwiftUI preview to
> try out your designs, you’ll find that any calls to `print()` are
> ignored. If you’re using `print()` for testing purposes – e.g. as simple
> button tap actions – then this can be a real headache.
>
> Fortunately, there’s a simple fix: right-click on the play button in
> the preview canvas and choose “Debug Preview”. With that small change
> made you’ll find your `print()` calls work as normal.

Comment: thanks pawello2222, but that is what I'm doing.  it's in "Debug Preview", and still nothing prints out.

Comment: well searching around I find several people with the same problem.  who have, like me, been careful to use `Debug Preview` and to actually enable the debug console below.  So frustrating.